# Question about the percentages of sets in other sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am puzzling over the question:
If there are three sets, $A, B, $ and $C$, where:
$A \cap B \ne \emptyset$
$A \cap C \ne \emptyset$
$B \cap C \ne \emptyset$
i.e. $A, B$ and $C$ have to intersect in some way.
From there:
a) what % of set $D$ is contained inside set $A$ if $D=A \cap B$ ?
b) what % of set $E$ is contained inside set $A$ if $E=D \cap B$  (i.e. $A \cap B \cap C)$ ?
c) what % of set $F$ is contained inside set $A$ if $F$ is the triangle in the diagram below ?

State any variables that will have to be included to solve these problems.

[image: Triangle picture]

How should I start??

**EDIT:**
I meant what percentage of all items in $D, E$ or $F$ are contained in all of the items in $A$

Comment: Are you talking about the picture in question a) and b)?

Comment: What is $\otimes$; the empty set? And how is "%" defined for sets?

Comment: There is a symbol `\emptyset`, yielding $\emptyset$ that is more commonly used here...

Comment: If $D= A \cap B$, $D \subseteq A$ so I'd say a 100%. Ditto for b.

Comment: @LeoHö , the picture _can_ be used for a) and b)  but it isn't compulsory!

Comment: @mrtaurho, yes: $\otimes$ is an empty set, and I guess the % is the % of items in let's say, set $X$ in set $Y$

Comment: @Henno, sorry -- I didn't know $\emptyset$ existed!

Comment: @Leo I am sorry, the edit does not help me understand the question better. Could you mean something like what is $\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(A)}$ in $%$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I don't understand what you mean or your question has too few restrictions.

Based on what you said in the comments and the interpretation of your question, my answer is, it could be any percentage. Assume, e.g. that $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,3\}$ and $C=\{1,4\}$ then $D$ contains $50$% of A's elements. Now in comparison, if $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then D only contains $20$% of A's elements.

Answer (score 1):

For any sets $A, B$ such that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, $A \cap B$ represents the elements in both $A$ and $B$, therefore, by definition,

$$A\cap B \subset A \textrm{, and } A \cap B \subset B$$
Hence, 100% of $D = A \cap B$ is contained in A, and similarly, 100% of $E = A \cap B \cap C$ is contained in $A$.

Comment: Thanks @P.J.:  
please look at the edit -- I made the question hopefully clearer.

Comment: @Leo I think you have made the question less clear.